# How can I stop triggering the onChange event of a textbox in below mentioned scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

How can I stop triggering the onChange event of a textbox in below mentioned scenario?

I have two text boxes on an aspx page;
If user change first text box value and its onChange event there is an asynchronous service call which updating the second textbox. During service call the control shifted on the second textbox. As the second text box value has been changed before it got focus, It triggers the second TextBox onChange event.

Comment: Couldn't you set the second textbox's onchange event in the first textboxes ajax callback? Or have a variable like `textboxUpdating` which is set to `true` when your ajax starts and then use something like: `yourAjax.done(function(){ textboxUpdating = false; })`. In the second textbox's onchange event you can have this at the top of the function `if(textboxUpdating) return;` and the rest of it won't be executed.

Comment: What triggers the onchange? The user or the code?

Comment: `As the second text box value has been changed before it got focus, It triggers the second TextBox onChange event.` - that doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: Something to take note of - I don't believe the `onChange` event is fired unless the value is changed when focus moves away from the control, or `.change` is called on that textbox. For example if you call `$("input[type=text]").change()`, it will fire the `onChange` event on all text inputs. So, unless this service call calls this method on the 2nd checkbox, or focuses and unfocuses it, `onChange` will not be called.